# How to upload an image on server directory

Tags: asp-classic, upload

Hi on java applet part I am using below code to send the request to upload.asp page to upload image in server directory.Please tell me in asp classic how can I upload the image in server directory without using third party dll

```
  Dimension size = perfchart.getSize();
  BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(size.width,
            size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics2D g2 = myImage.createGraphics();
  perfchart.paint(g2);

  URL url = new URL(uploadURL);

  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  connection.setDoOutput(true);

  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

  connection.setDoInput(true);  

  connection.setUseCaches(false);
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/png");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + FIELD_NAME +"\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
  output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

  output.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n"); // throws IOException
  ImageIO.write(image, imageType, output);
```

so please tell me how can I upload the image by asp classic. Is there any requirement to change in this java code please tell me that also

Comment: Not sure what's it got to do with wordpress?

Comment: As this is about a java applet in conjunction with an upload ASP page I guess this is not related to WordPress at least not first-hand. Voting to close.

Comment: He probably confused this with StackOverflow. Should be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for classic asp:

http://www.asp101.com/articles/jacob/scriptupload.asp

and Pure asp upload: (server is not responding right now!)

http://freeaspupload.net

However I suggest using .net solutions if your server has .net enabled:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

and

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140211/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091201-1.shtml